# Android date from SqlLite depend on GMT

Tags: android

In android I am using `SqlLite` with `MyDate` row like `DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. But when i am reading date i get date one hour back because i am using `GMT + 1` in my android environment.

```
MyDate: 12:03 
Android date: 13:03
```

When reading from `SqlLite` how can i convert it to `GMT + X`, depends on android environment?

EDIT:

code:

```
     Cursor cursor = logsDao.getAll(LogsDao.KEY_ID + " DESC", "100");
            String[] columns = new String[] { LogsDao.KEY_CONTENT, LogsDao.KEY_COMMENT, LogsDao.KEY_CREATED };
            int[] to = new int[] { R.id.logContext, R.id.logComment, R.id.logCreated };
            SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.log_entry, cursor, columns, to);
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that first you should store your retrieved data in a Timestamp with UCT timezone, then update the current Timezone in according with the one of the mobilephone.

```
String s = "2013-02-11 12:03:00";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UCT"));
Date timestamp = null;
try {
    timestamp = df.parse(s);
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You need to [implement a custom cursorAdapter](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/) and in the method bindView manipuulate your date

```
@Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor c) {
        String date;
        date= c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LogsDao.KEY_CREATED));

        //implement change of timezone

        TextView date_text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.date);
        if (date_text != null) {
            date_text.setText(date);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you. I update my question because I don't know how to use this code in SimpleCursorAdapter

Comment: you need to implement a custom cursorAdapter http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/11/custom-cursoradapters/